# struts2 in gae:: Fetching Url working in local but not in domain

Tags: java, google-app-engine, struts2, urlfetch

I'm trying to fetch an URL using struts2 framework. It works in local environment, but not when I host in domain. But the same URL when I tried to access using simple servlet application it works both in local and domain.
Is there any config changes required for struts2 application while hosting in domain?

The URL that I'm fetching is inside my firewall.

```
try {
    String QueryString=request.getQueryString();
    URL dataURL = new URL("http://test.com/contact-insert-entry?emid=" + QueryString);
    System.out.println("dataURL::"+dataURL);
    HTTPRequest fetchreq = new HTTPRequest(dataURL);
    fetchreq.setHeader(new HTTPHeader("use_intranet","true"));
    fetchresp = fetcher.fetch(fetchreq);
    System.out.println("Fetch Response::"+fetchresp.getResponseCode());
}
```

Comment: even BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dataURL.openStream())); doesn't work in domain.

Comment: what the exception or error you are getting?

Comment: best part is I can't see any  error/exception in the logs on Domain.

Comment: What happens if you log into your domain server and try and access that URL via a browser?

Comment: I can access that URL via a browser,No issues with it

Comment: Well that eliminates firewall issues then. Have you tried running this action in the Firefox browser with the Firebug debugger enabled and looking at what the browser is sending and what the server is returning?

Comment: @user497087 Can you point me to that how and where to check response from server in firebug.I don't see any neither the browser sending data like "http://test.com/contact-insert-entry?emid=test@test.com" nor server response from server.Can you help me out here too?

Comment: This all what I see here  REQUEST HEADER AS :: "POST /gst-Submit.action?emid=test@test.com HTTP/1.1"  and Response Header as :: Server - Google Fronted

Comment: Open the "Net" tab in Firebug and select All - you should then be able to examine what the browser sends and what the server sees